# set background gradients position relative to edge of element?

Tags: css

I have a css element that needs a background element that starts 
one pixel from the left border
one pixel from the top border

and that ends
one pixel from the right border
two pixels from the top border

Is this doable? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using CSS property `background-position: 1px 1px;`

Edit: You can also do it like `background-position: right top;`

Or you can do it like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    right: /*Whatever*/;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's great, but what about relative to the right corner? I don't know the width of the element.

Comment: But I need an offset of one pixel :)

Comment: @KristofferNolgren Updated, you can have nested div's here